# BigQuery Timestamp Offset

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to get up and running using the TIMESTAMP offset functions, as the offset is important for grouping the DAY/WEEK/MONTH/QUARTER/YEAR values in the date functions. I've attempted to do some experiments using the TIMESTAMP function, but it does not seem to be accepting the offset at all.

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(TIMESTAMP("2012-06-24 19:06:56")); //works
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(TIMESTAMP("2012-06-24 19:06:56 -07:00")); //does not work
```

The non-working TIMESTAMP example is the one that is provided in the documentation. Has anyone been able to successfully work with timezone offsets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to translate by a constant hour offset, can you use
`DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP("2012-06-24 19:06:56"), -7, "HOUR")` ?

Comment: I want to do it when I load, not when I'm querying. The issue is for 3rd party engines (Tableau) when they're doing their thing. Is this feature working as documented?

Comment: Timezone offset should work on load. We have a open that we should make it work on query too.

Comment: Thought it might be useful to link to the bigquery DATE_ADD documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#date_add